# Improve guidelines about asking good questions when it comes to formatting

Tags: discussion, help-center, formatting

I am trying to make clear that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53142042/power-bi-data-modeling) lacks proper formatting preventing it from being readable. I was looking at the help pages to see if it says something about formatting but could not find it. Would it not help if we include a section about formatting in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page?

I think we should use most of the things listened in the paragraph *Spelling, grammar and formatting* of [the blogpost](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) written by Jon Skeet. Having a link to this blogpost is not enough I think.

Comment: Even with the added newlines, that question is far from being great, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, but that is not the point.

Comment: I do not disagree, but my point is that telling a user that posts a such a question that the question's problem is _readability_ is kinda misleading, IMO. While good formatting is obviously much appreciated, it can always be edited in. But good formatting does not make a good question.

Comment: Like when people edit closed questions to correct some formatting without making the question on-topic, which steals the one chance the OP had to push their question into the reopen queue via an edit. Sure it is "improving the post", but it isn't fixing the problem.